# Wordpress; PHP functions inside Ajax requests not working. Alternative?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

When calling a PHP page with Ajax (in my Wordpress theme), the PHP `echo 'Hello World!';` works fine, but calling other Wordpress PHP functions such as `get_bloginfo();`, the function returns undefined. Is it possible to use Wordpress functions inside ajax calls? What are the other options.. I know iframes may work. I am trying to load a page that outputs plugin functionality.

The error that pops up is {Fatal Error: Call to undefined function get_bloginfo() in ... }

Comment: That doesnt sound right. Those functions should work as long as you're in the WP enviroment...

Comment: Following on @elclanrs question, is there any chance you're referring to a script outside of Wordpress?

Comment: The script is an addon script to a theme I'm building. So in the page, I'm using a anchor link (with the ajax plugin class) to call another page (that does use get_header and get_footer...

Comment: You need to make sure the following appears if the script is outside of the normal WordPress functionality:

    <?php require( '/path/to/wordpress/root/wp-load.php' ); ?>

Comment: btw, the script is in a directory of the theme, though not hooked into Wordpress anyplace besides the footer (where javascript is called).

Answer (score 2):

I did not test it, try some thing like below using plugin

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:  Blog information
 * Plugin URI: http://www.test.com/
 * Description: Displays Blog information
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: your_name
 * Author URI: http://www.test.com/
*/
// Function for handling AJAX requests
function getblog_request_handler() {

    // Check that all parameters have been passed
    if ((isset($_REQUEST['request']) && ($_REQUEST['request'] == 'getblog_Action'))) {
        // Output the response from your call and exit
        echo get_bloginfo();
        exit();
    }
    elseif (isset($_REQUEST['request']) && ($_REQUEST['request'] == 'getblog_Action'))   {
        // Otherwise display an error and exit the call
        echo "Error: Unable to display request.";
        exit();
    }

}

// Add the handler to init()
add_action('init', 'getblog_request_handler');

?>
```

And use JS to call plugin function to get response,

```
....

        jQuery.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "index.php",
            data    : { 
                        request    : "getblog_Action"
                      },
            success : function(response) {
                                   alert(response);
                //jQuery(".blog_name").html(response);
                            }
        });  
....
```

When ever you call this ajax, you will get blog information using ajax.

Comment: Thank you for the response and awesome code, but including wp-load.php did it.

Comment: @user1273237 Have you tried with above plugin ? I think you can follow this way to make an ajax call in wordpress

Comment: The `elseif` is never executed. It matches the `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a whole separate way you need to make Ajax calls within WordPress. [edit: what I mean is, there is a prescribed way; whether you need to follow it religiously or whether there are other ways to skin the cat is another story] There are tutorials aplenty (just do a websearch for "Ajax WordPress" and look for the articles that talk about implementation rather than just now Ajax is used to power its back end).

The short version is:

You should be making your calls to a particular handler, 'admin-ajax.php' and you should do it with a POST. You pass a data object that looks something like 'action=someaction&parameter=foo'.

Then you should have a hook in functions.php for the "someaction" action.

There's more to it, but I don't think this is the best place for a tutorial. Suffice it to say, you need to delve more into it; you can't just make an Ajax call the way you would with a straight-up markup+JavaScript page.

But it can be done. Contact forms in WP are often based on Ajax, so they might have sample code worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

WP Commands like `get_bloginfo()` should be working.

Are you sure you have included all the appropriate wordpress headers (in the responding script)?

Comment: yes, regular echo will display output, but it seems when going back to wordpress to built in functions, errors are output.

Comment: Well, a "regular `echo`" would display in any PHP script. Is there anything like `<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
?>` at the top of your PHP script?

Comment: Why would require be used here? I am using ajax to get the file.

Comment: Well, so you've got one file using ajax (let's say main.php) and one php script (let's say `result.php`) delivering the results (e.g. from `get_bloginfo()`). What I'm saying is that the WP Headers (wp-blog-header.php) MUST be included in your `result.php` file...

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. Thank you so much. I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: AND yes, as the other guy mentioned, try using POST requests (not GET).

Answer (score 0):

I was recently facing one similar kind of issue as I was unable to call methods with `$this->myMethod()`, and unable to access variables with `$this->myVariable`. It seems like class is not being instantiated or may be the ajax method is acting like a static method so `$this` has no existence within it. Though the class is being instantiated for sure as this method is being called and class constructor is also setting up things.

The solution I am able to work out with is making my other variables and methods `static`, and now they were accessible by `self::myMethod()` and `self::$myVariable`